# Ordering query Crosstab Postgres

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I'm trying to pivot a table in Postgres. My table 'sample' has many columns (code, sector, item, year, period, value, preorder), instead of having 1 concept, 1 year, 1 value per row, i want the concept with values by year. From this;

```
Item            Value   Year    PreOrder
Sales             50    2011    1
Costs            -20    2011    2
GrossProfit       30    2011    3
Expenses          -5    2011    4
Tax               -3    2011    5
Profit            22    2011    6
Sales             45    2012    3
Costs            -20    2012    4
GrossProfit       25    2012    5
Expenses          -5    2012    6
Tax               -3    2012    7
Profit            17    2012    8
```

To this:

```
Item        2011    2012
Sales         50    45
Costs        -20    -20
GrossProfit   30    25
Expenses      -5    -5
Tax           -3    -3
Profit        22    17
```

Using crosstab in Postgres:

```
Select * from crosstab($$Select item, year, value from sec_sample
    Where cik=320193
    AND period='Annual'
    AND Sector='Agro'
    Order by year, preorder
    $$,
    $$VALUES ('2011'::int), ('2012')$$)
AS value("item" varchar(255), "2011" numeric(20,2), "2012" numeric(20,2));
```

However this results in:

```
Item        2011    2012
Sales         50    
Costs        -20    
GrossProfit   30    
Expenses      -5    
Tax           -3    
Profit        22    
Sales               45
Costs              -20
GrossProfit         25
Expenses            -5
Tax                 -3
Profit              17
```

Any idea how i can modify my query? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, to group by `item` you have to order by `item`:

```
Select * from crosstab($$Select item, year, value from sec_sample
    Where cik=320193
    AND period='Annual'
    AND Sector='Agro'
    Order by item, year, preorder
    $$,
    $$VALUES ('2011'::int), ('2012')$$)
AS value("item" varchar(255), "2011" numeric(20,2), "2012" numeric(20,2));
```

But you can pivot without using `crosstab`, like this:

```
select
    s.item,
    sum(case when s.year = 2011 then s.value else 0 end) as "2011",
    sum(case when s.year = 2012 then s.value else 0 end) as "2012"
from sec_sample as s
group by s.item
order by min(s.preorder)
```

I think it's easier to modify this type of query

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/74b2d/6)</kbd>**

Comment: I tried your query and although it groups by orders it shouldn't order by item but by the column 'preorder'. Ordering by item ordered them alphabetically, which is not really the desired result. See my example.

Comment: @Bondifrench I've changed the second query, now it's ordered